# Couldn't find homography while image stitching

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, homography, image-stitching

I am trying to stitch multiple images. At first 9 photo my code works well, when it comes to stitch one more couple images(left and right) it couldn't find any homography and returns an error message like: "The input arrays should have at least 4 corresponding point sets to calculate Homography". In below you can see part of my code. I can't figure it out how to deal with that or what is the wrong with my code.

```
def get_transform(src, dst):
    first_points, second_points = feature_matching(src, dst)

    src_pts = np.float32(first_points).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
    dst_pts = np.float32(second_points).reshape(-1, 1, 2)
    M, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC)

return M, first_points, second_points, mask
```

Comment: Check whether there are at least 4 matches before calling findHomography.

Comment: What if there are less than 4 matches? I don't understand what should I do at that point. If I skip that image next one also won't be matched

Comment: Use other inages or other features. If there are 3 matches you could try affine affine transformatio, but honestly,if there are only 3 or even only 4 matches, you will have a high risk that a computed transformation leads to a wrong or bad stitching.

Comment: You could also let the user manually click correspondences in both images, if that is appropriate in your use-case.

Comment: I will probably try to let the user decide, thank you sir!